# How to open virtual key board in caps lock mode in android?

Tags: android

I am trying to open soft virtual keyboard in caps lock mode when user click on edittext box.

I have tried the following code `android:inputType="textCapCharacters"`, but it's not working.

How to solve my problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `android:capitalize="characters"` to the EditText properties. This should display the keyboard in CAPS.

Also FYI, this is how you show the keyboard via code:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEdit);
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
// only will trigger it if no physical keyboard is open
mgr.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Comment: try using android:inputType="textCapWords".. this is work for me in android 2.3

Comment: on which version you are debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:capitalize="characters"` to the EditText properties. This should display the keyboard in CAPS.

Answer (score 0):

android:capitalize="characters" will work.

if not,try like this.

EditText et;

et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {            

}
    @Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {             
}
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
      String st=arg0.toString();
  if(!st.equals(st.toUpperCase()))
  {
     st=st.toUpperCase();
     et.setText(st);
  }
}
```

});

Comment: i am putting image,what i want .